# How can I view rows vertically in SQLCMD?

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

In my `psql` I used to set `\X` for enabling `Expanded Display` and view my rows data with column names along side. Can I get this in `SQLCMD` as well?

Comment: try referring to the help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility

Comment: @Squirrel: Had tried `sqlcmd /?`. But had no luck.

Answer (score 0):

No such thing in SQLCMD. What you want to do is to use  the pivot clause in SQLServer.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx